# Open, print and close report by running through list of parameters

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an order form report that pulls from a query using an order reference number, when doing orders in bulk I have to shift-f9 to refresh the query with a new number and print to pdf. Is there any way macro or VBA to input a list or preferably a set of parameters.

Say I would like to pull up and print orders 1-100. Instead of manually refreshing the report a hundred times and printing how could I instruct access to do this for me? Bonus points if I can set parameters to fill in the title of the PDF...

Sorry if this is a simple question. I attempted googling it but I don't think I was using the correct terms.

Comment: You will get a lot more help here posting your existing code and asking questions about it.

Comment: @enderland I actually don't have any code. I wouldn't even know where to start with VBA/Macros. I'm sorry to say.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the title of the PDF, I assume you mean the file name? Since you've not mentioned the name of any title parameter used for the report.

```
Sub printPDF(firstRec As Integer, lastRec As Integer, rptTitle As String)
Dim recCount As Integer
recCount = firstRec
Do Until recCount = lastRec
    DoCmd.SetParameter "[paramName]", recCount
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "[reportName]", acFormatPDF, CurrentProject.Path & "\" & rptTitle & "_" & recCount & ".pdf", False
    recCount = recCount + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Change [reportName] to the name of your report, and [paramName] to the name of the parameter you (presumably) pass for the record ID. You should then get .pdf files named [title]_[orderNo].pdf for order numbers from firstRec to lastRec.

Comment: Yes, the file name sorry. I will try this code and let you know if it worked. It looks promising.